# What does 'printf -v' do?

Tags: bash, printf

After having come across several times this `printf -v` in bash script examples on the net, as well as several questions on stackoverflow, I could not find a proper explanation in the `printf` manpages.

`man printf` or `man 3 printf` do not help me.

Where do I have to look for?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are several **printf** commands within Linux:

1. **printf** the known C function (described in `man 3 printf`)
2. **GNU coreutils printf**, located in `/usr/bin/printf` (see [`man 1 printf`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html) or [`info coreutils printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/printf-invocation.html))
3. Bash's **builtin printf** (see the *SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS* section from [`man bash`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#SHELL_BUILTIN_COMMANDS) or [`info bash printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-printf) or `help printf`).

To find out, what you exactly need, use [`type <command>`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-type) to find out what is used in particular:

```
root@pi:~# type -a printf
printf is a shell builtin
printf is /usr/bin/printf
printf is /bin/printf
```

So number 3 is the solution here.

```
root@pi:~# help printf
printf: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
    Formats and prints ARGUMENTS under control of the FORMAT.
    
    Options:
      -v var    assign the output to shell variable VAR rather than
            display it on the standard output
    
    FORMAT is a character string which contains three types of objects: plain
    characters, which are simply copied to standard output; character escape
    sequences, which are converted and copied to the standard output; and
    format specifications, each of which causes printing of the next successive
    argument.
    
    In addition to the standard format specifications described in printf(1),
    printf interprets:
    
      %b    expand backslash escape sequences in the corresponding argument
      %q    quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input
      %Q    like %q, but apply any precision to the unquoted argument before
            quoting
      %(fmt)T   output the date-time string resulting from using FMT as a format
                string for strftime(3)
    
    The format is re-used as necessary to consume all of the arguments.  If
    there are fewer arguments than the format requires,  extra format
    specifications behave as if a zero value or null string, as appropriate,
    had been supplied.
    
    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless an invalid option is given or a write or assignment
    error occurs.
```

Comment: The help for the shell built-in `printf` can be found by running `help printf`.

Comment: @chepner Thank you, will add your answer to the answer.